# Problem with calling 4 async method paralel in constructor

Tags: c#, web, xamarin.forms, async-await, task

I have a problem with tasks in c#, and don't know how to use `async` `await`. I have 4 methods, something like:

```
private async Task Name(parameters) {}
```

How can I run all 4 methods simultaneously in the constructor, to reduce the execution time and optimize cpu usage.

I tried `Parallel.Invoke(() =>` but this not best solution....

Comment: `Task.WhenAll()`?

Comment: What problem are you having? Are you getting an error? Do you just want to know how to call four `async` methods in parallel?

Comment: Yes,to call 4 task method parallel executing in constructor view model page and wait to finish all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sample code:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
tasks[0] = Method0();
tasks[1] = Method1();
tasks[2] = Method2();
tasks[3] = Method3();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);// If you have to wait all the tasks to be finished.
//await Task.WhenAny(tasks); //If any of them finished.
```

**Update:**

Here is the full answer:

```
static async Task<List<int>> MethodTest(int i)
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    return new List<int>() { i, i, i };
}
async Task method()
{
    Task<List<int>>[] tasks = new Task<List<int>>[4];
    tasks[0] = MethodTest(0);
    tasks[1] = MethodTest(1);
    tasks[2] = MethodTest(2);
    tasks[3] = MethodTest(3);
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    Console.WriteLine(tasks[0].Result);
}
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for answer,but....After Task.WhenAll(tasks)...I have method where i am using list who need to have result from web api after finish tasks,but list is empty and i have exception Index out of range....I debagging and see that,BUT i notice that in the debbaging process when catch exception List get the data...but for me its too late...how to resolve that?

Comment: I update the answer, check it and let me know if there were any question.

Comment: Sorry i am not sure  how to implement this code in my project:OnLoadPrometDanKorisnikDatum(KorisnikID, PomocnaDnDDatnaDat, DatumVrednost); i have 4 similar method like this and how to implement MethodTest? Is MethodTest just create for await Task.Delay(10)?

Comment: I haven't any access to your project! :) What is your problem?

Comment: Can you go remote to my computer against TeamWeaver,to see what is happens?

Comment: Sorry I can't. please share your problem here.

Comment: I have 4 method which get data from web api in json format(and fill List of data),and that 4 method is this type:private async Task Name(parameters) {}     , in constructor of ViewModel i must to call that 4 method to execute paralely and to have fill List of data.After that with this list of data i fill Chart on xaml page.BUT: i try with your suggested code and after this line of code await Task.WhenAll(tasks); debug go on next line when use List of data of First method,He said that List is empty that dont have data and give exception...

Comment: Do you use await somewhere int your method? I mean `async Task Name(parameters){await //any code}`

Comment: Yes...Yes....I do when wait respond from web api...This is snippet code of Method...var respond = await service.GetAllPrometDanSaDatumomZaKorisnika(korisnikID, dnd, datum).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: Could you please upload your sample code on git? and give me the repo link?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yYwNlH_uJY-J4xRKCkogQBmYEdCvFxpc       This is ViewModel Page where is code...I dont know how to place whole project on git....Try with this please...Fokus on line code 172 that is how me works,and Method where me trying your code is UcitajSvePodatke() on 381,i commented this method when called in the construktor because dont work..

Comment: first of all replace this definition `private async void UcitajSvePodatke()` with `private async Task UcitajSvePodatke()`.

Comment: second, every where you use `UcitajSvePodatke()` should be converted to `await UcitajSvePodatke()`.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my post as answer and vote up if you find my comments and post helpful.

Comment: Ok,I would,and thank you but,how to place await UcitajSvePodatke() in the constructor page...that dont work...?

Comment: This dont want to work... on code await Task.WhenAll(tasks); when debbug he dont wait to program....

Comment: You can use `UcitajSvePodatke().wait()` in the constructor.

Comment: I try that but block program with that...

Comment: So your code does not meet the minimum requirements for parallelism.